# Why does my memory used (accounting for cache) does not correspond to my processes memory usage?

Tags: ubuntu, memory-usage, low-memory

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 where a number of background jobs run every day. `free` and `top` both report that 3.9GB of the 4GB of memory is in use (of which ~90MB is cache/buffers).

When I do a `top` of `ps aux` and count the memory usage of my apps, I get to about 50%.

I am only running mysql, apache+passenger, and redis on the machine. It also hosts an NFS share.

Is there another way to check the remaining 49% of in use memory? And to free it without rebooting the server?

This is the output of `free`:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       4010060    3820592     189468          0      84208     194168
-/+ buffers/cache:    3542216     467844
Swap:       741372     741292         80
```

`ps aux`:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  23864   472 ?        Ss   Feb02   0:13 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   2:32 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:14 [migration/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:25 [migration/1]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   1:30 [ksoftirqd/1]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [watchdog/1]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   5:17 [events/0]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   2:06 [events/1]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [cpuset]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [khelper]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [netns]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [async/mgr]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [pm]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:45 [sync_supers]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:47 [bdi-default]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [kintegrityd/0]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [kintegrityd/1]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:47 [kblockd/0]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:27 [kblockd/1]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [kacpid]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [kacpi_notify]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [kacpi_hotplug]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [ata_aux]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [ata_sff/0]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [ata_sff/1]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [khubd]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [kseriod]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [kmmcd]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:07 [khungtaskd]
root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02  53:01 [kswapd0]
root        34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Feb02   0:00 [ksmd]
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [aio/0]
root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [aio/1]
root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [crypto/0]
root        39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [crypto/1]
root        44  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [pciehpd]
root        45  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root        46  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root        47  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [kstriped]
root        49  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [kmpathd/0]
root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [kmpathd/1]
root        51  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [kmpath_handlerd]
root        52  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [ksnapd]
root        53  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [kondemand/0]
root        54  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [kondemand/1]
root        55  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [kconservative/0]
root        56  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [kconservative/1]
root       246  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   2:58 [mpt_poll_0]
root       256  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [mpt/0]
root       259  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root       278  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:08 [kdmflush]
root       282  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       297  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:36 [jbd2/dm-0-8]
root       298  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       299  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       338  0.0  0.0  17096     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
root       340  0.0  0.0 147836    80 ?        Ss   Mar02   7:54 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root       349  0.0  0.0  16880     0 ?        S<s  Feb02   0:00 udevd --daemon
root       554  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root       577  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02 127:26 [vmmemctl]
root       657  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02 126:36 [jbd2/sdb1-8]
root       658  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       659  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb02   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       788  0.0  0.0   6128     4 tty4     Ss+  Feb02   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
root       791  0.0  0.0   6128     4 tty5     Ss+  Feb02   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
root       793  0.0  0.0  49312   104 ?        Ss   Feb02   0:04 /usr/sbin/sshd
root       796  0.0  0.0   6128     4 tty2     Ss+  Feb02   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
root       797  0.0  0.0   6128     4 tty3     Ss+  Feb02   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
root       801  0.0  0.0   6128     4 tty6     Ss+  Feb02   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
daemon     804  0.0  0.0  18932     0 ?        Ss   Feb02   0:02 atd
root       805  0.0  0.0  21128   156 ?        Ss   Feb02   0:47 cron
root       851  0.0  0.0  11360   304 ?        Ss   Feb02  15:18 /usr/sbin/irqbalance
root      1374  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar16   0:01 [jbd2/dm-2-8]
root      1375  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar16   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1376  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar16   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      4088  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:58   0:00 [flush-251:0]
root      4329  0.0  0.0  70660   720 ?        Ss   11:59   0:00 sshd: myuser [priv]
myuser    4347  0.0  0.0  70660   744 ?        S    12:00   0:00 sshd: myuser@pts/1
myuser    4348  0.0  0.1  26028  6432 pts/1    Ss   12:00   0:00 -bash
munin     5150  0.0  0.0  39916  2040 ?        Ss   Apr08   8:04 /usr/sbin/munin-node
redis     8110  3.0 38.7 2244244 1553116 ?     Ss   May19  27:58 /usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/re
www-data  8433  0.0  0.0 148344  1928 ?        S    May17   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  8435  0.0  0.0 148336  2132 ?        S    May17   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
myuser   10115  0.0  0.0  26624   592 ?        Ss   12:50   0:00 SCREEN -dR
myuser   10116  0.0  0.0  22808  2548 pts/0    Ss   12:50   0:00 /bin/bash
root     11410  0.0  0.0  27248   396 ?        Ss   Mar16   0:03 rpc.idmapd
root     11439  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar16   0:00 [lockd]
root     11440  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar16   0:03 [nfsd4]
root     11441  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar16   0:00 [nfsd4_callbacks]
root     11442  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar16   0:19 [nfsd]
root     11443  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar16   0:21 [nfsd]
root     11444  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar16   0:20 [nfsd]
root     11445  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar16   0:22 [nfsd]
root     11446  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar16   0:21 [nfsd]
root     11447  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar16   0:20 [nfsd]
root     11448  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar16   0:21 [nfsd]
root     11449  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar16   0:20 [nfsd]
root     11453  0.0  0.0  19032   316 ?        Ss   Mar16   0:09 /usr/sbin/rpc.mountd --manage-gids
myapp     11886  0.0  0.0  11984   196 pts/0    S+   13:03   0:00 /bin/bash shared/worker.sh
myapp     11887  0.1  2.0 180724 81252 pts/0    S+   13:04   0:03 resque-1.10.0: Forked 14745 at 1305
myapp     13085  0.1  2.0 195248 83180 ?        S    13:17   0:03 Rails: /var/www/myapp-prd/current
myapp     14745 80.9  2.0 185908 80900 pts/0    R+   13:29  19:09 resque-1.10.0: Processing myapp_import
www-data 15516  0.0  0.0 148224  1608 ?        S    May17   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
myuser   17579  0.0  0.0  17760  1220 pts/1    R+   13:53   0:00 ps aux
mysql    18736  2.5  1.1 345568 46396 ?        Ssl  Mar16 2349:04 /usr/sbin/mysqld
daemon   21340  0.0  0.0   8304     4 ?        Ss   Mar16   0:00 portmap
statd    21564  0.0  0.0  14600     4 ?        Ss   Mar16   0:00 rpc.statd -L
root     21823  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar16   0:00 [rpciod/0]
root     21824  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar16   0:00 [rpciod/1]
www-data 22353  0.0  0.0 148484  1352 ?        S    May16   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     23471  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar16   0:00 [kslowd000]
root     23472  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar16   0:00 [kslowd001]
root     23473  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar16   0:00 [nfsiod]
www-data 27001  0.0  0.0 148496  1588 ?        S    May17   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     27365  0.0  0.0  23432    20 ?        Ssl  May15   0:00 PassengerWatchdog
root     27368  0.0  0.0 164064  1064 ?        Sl   May15   6:51 PassengerHelperAgent
root     27370  0.0  0.2  61904  8408 ?        S    May15   0:02 Passenger spawn server
nobody   27373  0.0  0.0  72172    28 ?        Sl   May15   0:01 PassengerLoggingAgent
www-data 27383  0.0  0.0 148356  1740 ?        S    May15   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 27384  0.0  0.0 148492  1444 ?        S    May15   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 27385  0.0  0.0 148224  1568 ?        S    May15   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 27386  0.0  0.0 148496  1860 ?        S    May15   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     29402  0.0  0.0  16876     4 ?        S<   Mar16   0:00 udevd --daemon
root     29800  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar16   0:00 [kdmflush]
root     29804  0.0  0.0  16876     4 ?        S<   Mar16   0:00 udevd --daemon
www-data 30231  0.0  0.0 148352  1904 ?        S    May16   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     31072  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May12   0:37 [flush-8:16]
syslog   31116  0.0  0.0 126028   388 ?        Sl   May12   0:04 rsyslogd -c4
root     32217  0.0  0.0   6128     4 tty1     Ss+  Mar17   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

`cat /proc/meminfo`:

```
MemTotal:        4010060 kB
MemFree:          155604 kB
Buffers:           48232 kB
Cached:           149308 kB
SwapCached:        42036 kB
Active:          1572044 kB
Inactive:         639616 kB
Active(anon):    1496792 kB
Inactive(anon):   517464 kB
Active(file):      75252 kB
Inactive(file):   122152 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:        741372 kB
SwapFree:             64 kB
Dirty:              1532 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1972572 kB
Mapped:             7920 kB
Shmem:                96 kB
Slab:              24384 kB
SReclaimable:      12224 kB
SUnreclaim:        12160 kB
KernelStack:        1368 kB
PageTables:        11632 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     2746400 kB
Committed_AS:    3150752 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      281448 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359449320 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       12288 kB
DirectMap2M:     4132864 kB
```

One of the things I notice is the high value of `Active(anon):    1496792 kB`, which according to the docs is:

> Memory that has been used more recently and usually not reclaimed unless absolutely necessary.

That's almost 1.5GB right there, is that normal? I do have very long (permanent) running processes (Resque) that fork each time a job comes in.

Comment: Could you post the output of `free`, and of `ps aux`? Maybe we spot something.

Comment: Added `free`, `ps aux`, and `cat /proc/meminfo` output.

Comment: In my opinion this is a normal behaviour of your linux machine.
check out this link for an easy explanation of the memory management in linux:
http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: I am not sure, I don't see that much caching or buffers going on in the `free` output compared to the memory in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your /proc/meminfo output, that will be provide more details of how your memory is beig used. Refer to this article to decipher the terms, scroll down to the meminfo section.

http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt

Comment: Never got to accept your answer, but this was really helpful in determining my applications memory usage.